# как отправить get запрос js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

в лучшем случае это jquery вариант, но значения не имеет.
Нужно сделать запрос вида `http://api.site.ru/requestpass/{username}&{phone}`
Запрос не является типичным для get, но возможности сменить вид запроса нет. Как можно данные через ajax получить?

Comment: а в чем проблемма при отправке такого запроса? чего то я не совсем понял суть проблеммы!

Comment: @Victor насколько мне известно get имеет вид `site.ru?param=1&param2=2`. jquery сам поймет, как подставить параметры?

Comment: главное что бы ваш сервер смог справится с вашим `URL` типа `/{username}&{phone}`

Comment: @Victor такой и нужен. Не создавал бы вопрос тогда)

Comment: Вы правильно сказали, что гет запрос передает параметры в виде `site.ru?param=1&param2=2`. Если же вам нужно в виде `/{username}&{phone}`   то это будет тот же гет запрос просто параметры вы "запрятали" в урл и серверу придется их парсить из урла!

Comment: @Victor понял, сейчас затестю

Comment: Может быть ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Сложность у вас заключается в подстановке данных в url?

Если да, тогда вот такой пример думаю вам поможет:

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var username = $('.username').val();
    var phone = $('.phone').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.site.ru/requestpass/' + username + '&' + phone,
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
});
```

Заменяете селекторы на свои и отправляете на такой url данные.

Answer (score 1):

```
var phone = '1', username = '2',
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', `http://api.site.ru/requestpass/${username}&${phone}`);
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function xhr (url, method,  data, callBack) {
    var xmlhttp      = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200);
            callBack(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
        xmlhttp.open(method, url);
        xmlhttp.send(data);
};

function xhrRequest  (src) {
    this.xhr( "ваш url (src)" , "GET", null, response);
};

function response  (obj) {
    var obj;
    try {
        var obj = JSON.parse(obj)
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```